# Calcular distancia entre dos puntos api google maps php

Tags: php, google-maps, api

Teniendo los puntos necesito calcular la distancia que hay entre ellos para hacer un calculo de un precio, ¿como podria hacerlo desde php?
Hacerlo desde el frontend con la api de javascript seria inseguro porque podrian inyectar una distancia que no es la correcta

Comment: ¿Encontraron alguna solución? yo ando por las miasmas.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que la tierra es un esferoide, no se puede usar la distancia cartesiana entre dos puntos (salvo en casos muy puntuales). Lo que quieres hacer se puede hacer de dos maneras.

1. Con la [ley esférica de los cosenos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)
2. Con la [fórmula de Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Empecemos pensando que tus puntos son

```
$lat0 = 45.50;
$lng0 = 15.47;
$lat1 = 35.15;
$lng1 = 16.12;
```

Y sus respectivas transformaciones a radianes (porque después verás que se trabaja con radianes.

```
$rlat0 = deg2rad($lat0);
$rlng0 = deg2rad($lng0);
$rlat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
$rlng1 = deg2rad($lng1);
```

Y la diferencia entre éstos valores (también se usa más adelante)

```
$latDelta = $rlat1 - $rlat0;
$lonDelta = $rlng1 - $rlng0;
```

**Usando ley esférica de los cosenos**

```
$distance = (6371 *
    acos(
        cos($rlat0) * cos($rlat1) * cos($lonDelta) +
        sin($rlat0) * sin($rlat1)
    )
);

echo 'distanct arcosine ' . $distance;
```

Nótese que 6371 es el radio de la tierra en KM. Si quieres la distancia en metros, le pones 6371000, y si quieres la distancia en millas, pulgadas, etc... bueno, ya me entiendes.

Para el ejemplo, la distancia resultante son **1152.1745200602 Km**

**Con la fórmula de Haversine**

```
$distance2 = 6371 * 2 * asin(
    sqrt(
        cos($rlat0) * cos($rlat1) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2) +
        pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2)
    )
);

echo 'distance haversine ' . $distance2;
```

Y el resultado, para nuestra sorpresa, también es **1152.1745200602 Km**

(hay casos en donde los resultados difieren, por ejemplo cuando las coordenadas son antípodas entre sí, o estás cerca de los polos).

Hay una aproximación usando la [proyección equirectangular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection), pero no entiendo esa proyección, no trabajo con ella, no conozco la fórmula y prefiero hacer como si no existiera.

**Disclaimer**:

Trabajo con mapas y aplicaciones GIS llevadas a la web usando Google Maps y Leaflet como base. El primer prototipo del producto tenía PHP como backend. Por eso he tenido que aprender estas cosas.

Comment: Pero ese calculo no toma en cuenta la ruta mas corta, el sentido de las vias y esas variables que si calcula google maps, yo puedo calcularlo en el frontend con la api de javascript, pero podrian inyectar una distancia que no es, por eso  necesito lo mismo pero en el backend para yo calcular la distancia y sacar los calculos correctos

Comment: Ah, ya entiendo. Quieres usar directions API para que te entregue una ruta y calcular el largo de esa ruta. Si un día de estos tengo tiempo voy a poner un ejemplo para usar google directions API desde el backend. Obviamente la respuesta es muy distinta

Comment: Bueno sigo buscando la solucion, te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando Google Directions API , esta misma te lo devuelve en el response. Tenemos el siguiente segmento de codigo de una funcion que traza una ruta

```
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(map) {

        var directionsServiceTmp = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplayTmp = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

        location_ini = 14.595188 + ',' + -90.5166266;
        location_fin = 14.641828 + ',' + -90.5152771;

        directionsServiceTmp.route({
            origin: location_ini,
            destination: location_fin,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                // Aqui con el response podemos acceder a la distancia como texto 
                console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text);
                // Obtenemos la distancia como valor numerico en metros 
               console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);

                directionsDisplayTmp.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
        directionsDisplayTmp.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para calcular la distancia entre 2 puntos necesitas saber las coordenadas x e y
sabiendo que la distancia entre los puntos es igual a la diferencia entre las x y la diferencia entre las y, osea tendrias que hacer algo por el estilo

```
<?php
   function calculaDistancia($longitud1, $latitud1, $longitud2, $latitud2){

       //calculamos la diferencia de entre la longitud de los dos puntos
       $diferenciaX = $longitud1 - $longitud2;

       //ahora calculamos la diferencia entre la latitud de los dos puntos
       $diferenciaY = $latitud1 -$latitud2;

       // ahora ponemos en practica el teorema de pitagora para calcular la distancia
       $distancia = sqrt(pow($diferenciaX,2) + pow($diferenciaY,2));
    }
?>
```

la funcion `sqrt()` sirve para hacer la raiz cuadrada, mientra la funcion `pow()` sirve para calcular la potencia

para obtener las coordenadas podes utilizar la geocodificacion de google que podes encontrar en este [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=es)

espero que te sea util

Comment: Pero ese calculo no toma en cuenta la ruta mas corta, el sentido de las vias y esas variables que si calcula google maps, yo puedo calcularlo en el frontend con la api de javascript, pero podrian inyectar una distancia que no es, por eso  necesito lo mismo pero en el backend para yo calcular la distancia y sacar los calculos correctos